# How to install Realtek Wireless Drives

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 13.04, realtek

Just incase I' will give you this

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvA Wireless 
    LAN Controller [10ec:8171] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1467]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192se
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1605]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

So the main problem is my internet connection cuts out time from time but now I found out I need to install the driver for it. RTL81912 SE. I have the file downloaded but I don't know how to install it. If I am missing some information I will try to give out what I can. I just am tired of my internet connection cutting out from time to time. Also whenever I move closer to the router it still sometimes cuts out too.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Ubuntu have you ?  few weeks ago I bought my new HP Laptop and I tried to install on it Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I couldn't get an internet connection at all. I had to an external usb wireless adaptor. Then I had the idea to try and install the LATEST version of Ubuntu (13.04) and that pretty much solved my problem. The 13.04 installation automatically detected the realtek drivers and I no longer had to use the wireless adaptor. Try upgrading to the latest version (if you are using any other version but 13.04) and if that also doesn't work, go to System Settings --> Software & Updates --> Additional Drivers Tab.

Please let me know for further details.

Regards, 
Anthie G.